# Android app crashes instantly after adding RealmReactPackage

Tags: android, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I followed the instructions from the realm page and did these steps:

- `npm install realm`
- `react-native link realm` --> For iOS everything works out without any further steps at this point.
- Opened android studio and updated changes in settings.gradle, app/build.gradle and imported the `RealmReactPackage` in `MainApplication.java`

If I build and start the app, everything is working out fine. Then I add `new RealmReactPackage()` to the list to the other ReactPackages.

If I start the app now, the app crashes immediately. The logcat doesn't say any reason for the crash, but I add the output anyways below.

**Things I tried already:**

- Clear caches
- Restart packager
- Deinstall app from emulator
- Clear node-modules and run `npm install` again and repeat the steps from above

**My setup:**

- "react": "16.3.1",
- "react-native": "0.55.4",
- "react-native-navigation": "v2.0.1937"
- Node version 9.5.0
- Android Studio version: 3.1.3

**What I didn't do so far:**

There is one instruction at the realm site under `Examples`:

`Note that on Android, you need the NDK installed and must have set the ANDROID_NDK environment variable.`

`export ANDROID_NDK=/usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r10e`

***My Question is, is this relevant for my config or just for the examples?***

**LogCat Output:**

```
    07-03 17:51:04.909  1664  1676 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.cowoperation/.MainActivity} from uid 2000
07-03 17:51:04.938  1664  2392 I ActivityManager: Start proc 32299:com.cowoperation/u0a91 for activity com.cowoperation/.MainActivity
07-03 17:51:05.319 32299 32325 V FA      : App package, google app id: com.cowoperation, 1:314188610363:android:2d8c823aa5045bd7
07-03 17:51:05.320 32299 32299 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.cowoperation/lib-main
07-03 17:51:05.320 32299 32325 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.cowoperation
07-03 17:51:05.320 32299 32299 I fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.cowoperation/lib-main
07-03 17:51:05.321 32299 32299 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.cowoperation/lib-main
07-03 17:51:05.654 32299 32345 I zygote  : Thread[30,tid=32345,Native,Thread*=0x88b19a00,peer=0x13214b48,"Thread-8"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.cowoperation-gxY-ptC8QV3xKg796vAtEA==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
07-03 17:51:05.808  1664  1690 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.cowoperation/.MainActivity: +878ms
07-03 17:51:05.880 32299 32325 V FA      : Event recorded: Event{appId='com.cowoperation', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6439080053319785913}]}
07-03 17:51:05.979 32299 32345 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.cowoperation, PID: 32299
07-03 17:51:05.979 32299 32345 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN5realm8jni_util9hack_initEv" referenced by "/data/app/com.cowoperation-gxY-ptC8QV3xKg796vAtEA==/lib/x86/librealmreact.so"...
07-03 17:51:05.980 32299 32345 E UncaughtException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN5realm8jni_util9hack_initEv" referenced by "/data/app/com.cowoperation-gxY-ptC8QV3xKg796vAtEA==/lib/x86/librealmreact.so"...
07-03 17:51:06.074 32299 32325 V FA      : Event recorded: Event{appId='com.cowoperation', name='app_exception(_ae)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6439080053319785913, timestamp=1530633065983, fatal=1}]}
07-03 17:51:06.153 32299 32325 V FA      : Event recorded: Event{appId='com.cowoperation', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=596, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6439080053319785913}]}
07-03 17:51:06.359  1664  2392 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.cowoperation/.MainActivity
07-03 17:51:06.373  1664  1684 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package com.cowoperation u0
07-03 17:51:06.569 32299 32325 V FA      : Event recorded: Event{appId='com.cowoperation', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=266, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-6439080053319785913}]}
```

Comment: What's the realm version? Update to latest version. `npm update realm`